# Jboss to exclude org.jboss.ws.jaxws-client module

Tags: web-services, jboss, cxf, jax-ws, saaj

I'm using `Jboss EAP 6.2`, in deployment phase I have this error:

```
20:04:24,161 |  |  SEVERE [org.apache.cxf.BusFactory] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Failed to determine BusFactory implementation class name.: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory
       at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getBusFactoryClass(BusFactory.java:395) [cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
       at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:316) [cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
       at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:303) [cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
       at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.getConduitInitiator(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:201)
       at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:69)
       at it.lispa.sire.finanziamentionline.service.integrazione.gapp.impl.GappClient.sendMessage(GappClient.java:233) [:]
       at it.lispa.sire.finanziamentionline.service.integrazione.gapp.impl.GappClient.verificaCartaCittadino(GappClient.java:95) [:]
```

I tried to exclude `org.jboss.ws.jaxws-client`module in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file for to use the `SoapConnectionImpl` of `Axis` library without success.

I resolved commenting this line in `JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\ws\saaj-impl\main\module.xml` (the comment is not mine):

```
<module name="org.jboss.ws.jaxws-client" services="import"/> <!-- to pull the jbossws-cxf SOAPConnection impl -->
```

I would like to solve the problem by configuring the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file, can you help me?

Thanks. Bye